# Save and Delete Sitecore 8.0 media files into Azure cloud storage

Tags: synchronization, sitecore, media, sitecore8

On a recent project of Siteore 8.1, we have the requirement to store media files (Images and PDFs) in Azure Storages.

Requirement is: - If any file is added or deleted in sitecore media library then same files should add/delete into Azure Storages.

What API should I Use to achieve the requirement.

Comment: There is no simple answer to this, there are so many options depending on the exact requirement. Do you just want to make use of Azure CDN, or to move the Media Library into Azure? Update and narrow your question, but here is one solution I have been working on: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/22/sitecore-media-library-in-azure-cloud-storage-part-3/

Comment: Want to move the Media Library into Azure and Use the URL of Azure to get the media

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly publish to reflect in CDN and can be implemented in the processor `Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem`